# Execute a large SQL script (with GO commands)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to execute a large set of SQL statements (creating a bunch of tables, views and stored procedures) from within a C# program.

These statements need to be separated by `GO` statements, but `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` does not like `GO` statements. My solution, which I suppose I'll post for reference, was to split the SQL string on `GO` lines, and execute each batch separately.

Is there an easier/better way?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) which understands GO separators. See my blog post here: [http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-*2D00*-the-easy-way](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx)

Sample code:

```
public static void Main()    
{        
  string scriptDirectory = "c:\\temp\\sqltest\\";
  string sqlConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
  "Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=(local)";
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(scriptDirectory);
  FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.sql");
  foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
  {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fi.FullName);
        string script = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
        }
   }
}
```

If that won't work for you, see Phil Haack's library which handles that: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/11/04/a-library-for-executing-sql-scripts-with-go-separators-and.aspx

Comment: How can this be integrated with a transaction? The code throws an InvalidOperationException when creating the ServerConnection with SqlConnection which has a pending transaction on it.

Comment: This solution works, I just want to add that if you want to use **transactions** with a `TransactionScope` object you just need to enlist the connection with the current ambient transaction. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18322938/1268570

Comment: works great, but can we use `SqlConnection.InfoMessage`) to see the result in C# application **or** save the result in `txt` file, just to know if the script was successfully executed , because recently using `sqlcmd` when i executed 150 mb script file on remote host,  after 55 minutes some rows were effected with this error, `TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` , `communication link failure`. ,  no of rows effected can be known , but i am concerned about error messages while running database generated script file.

Comment: This solutions caused a failure your code when some of SQL Dlls are not installed on the machine. .NET uses some dll's built in Windows. The absentence of  some  SQL feature packs (including Managment Objects) may prevent a errors something like 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll' not found. Fixing it(it is not easy work) next error will be 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BathParser.dll'  e.t.c Find other solution to ensure flexibility for your application.

Comment: This does not work, especially if there's an alter procedure statement in there. It just complains that it needs to be the first statement in a batch, which is is, because there's a batch separator right before it, but this still throws an error.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery is useless if you're trying to return results. And when you use ExecuteWithResults, it can't handle batch separators. Unbelievable. It also doesn't have any way to capture affected rows for individual statements the way SSMS does.

Comment: to use `Server Management Objects` does it a need that ssms is installed on the system?

Answer (score 39):

This is what I knocked together to solve my immediate problem.

```
private void ExecuteBatchNonQuery(string sql, SqlConnection conn) {
    string sqlBatch = string.Empty;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, conn);
    conn.Open();
    sql += "\nGO";   // make sure last batch is executed.
    try {
        foreach (string line in sql.Split(new string[2] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) {
            if (line.ToUpperInvariant().Trim() == "GO") {
                cmd.CommandText = sqlBatch;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlBatch = string.Empty;
            } else {
                sqlBatch += line + "\n";
            }
        }            
    } finally {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

It requires GO commands to be on their own line, and will not detect block-comments, so this sort of thing will get split, and cause an error:

```
ExecuteBatchNonQuery(@"
    /*
    GO
    */", conn);
```

Comment: It's nice that I can easily adapt this to SqlCe if needed -- the other code uses Sql connection classes and commands.

Comment: I want to run this code with a SQL script with several stored procedures within, but I'm a bit confused, where does it read the SQL?  When you refer to 'last batch' do you mean the SQL code? And if so, how would you determine the last batch, and what if I wanted to run all the batches not just the last? Too many questions I know, but thanks if you have the time to answer.

Comment: You pass the SQL to the function as a string: `string sql` - that's the entire script. When I refer to a "batch", I mean a chunk of SQL code between two "GO" statements. The code adds a `GO` to the end of the script so that the code inside the `foreach` won't skip the last batch if you didn't end your script with a `GO`. So the code as written will execute all the SQL.

Comment: I created an extension method:   internal static class SqlCommandHelper
    {
        internal static void ExecuteBatchNonQuery(this SqlCommand cmd, string sql)

Comment: If you want to be a wee bit more efficient you could use `StringBuilder sqlBatch` instead.

Comment: Another similar implementation using regex see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596876/go-statements-blowing-up-sql-execution-in-net/18597052#18597052

Comment: If my sql script file ends with GO, line => sql += "\nGO";   // make sure last batch is executed. causes the error

Answer (score 11):

You can use [SQL Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx) to perform this.  These are the same objects that Management Studio uses to execute queries.  I believe `Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery()` will perform what you need.

Answer (score 9):

I look at this a few times at the end decided with [EF implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/6.1.3/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs#L1494)
A bit modified for `SqlConnection`

```
public static void ExecuteSqlScript(this SqlConnection sqlConnection, string sqlBatch)
        {
            // Handle backslash utility statement (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207007.aspx)
            sqlBatch = Regex.Replace(sqlBatch, @"\\(\r\n|\r|\n)", string.Empty);

            // Handle batch splitting utility statement (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)
            var batches = Regex.Split(
                sqlBatch,
                string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"^\s*({0}[ \t]+[0-9]+|{0})(?:\s+|$)", BatchTerminator),
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

            for (int i = 0; i < batches.Length; ++i)
            {
                // Skip batches that merely contain the batch terminator
                if (batches[i].StartsWith(BatchTerminator, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    (i == batches.Length - 1 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(batches[i])))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Include batch terminator if the next element is a batch terminator
                if (batches.Length > i + 1 &&
                    batches[i + 1].StartsWith(BatchTerminator, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    int repeatCount = 1;

                    // Handle count parameter on the batch splitting utility statement
                    if (!string.Equals(batches[i + 1], BatchTerminator, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        repeatCount = int.Parse(Regex.Match(batches[i + 1], @"([0-9]+)").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < repeatCount; ++j)
                    {
                       var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                       command.CommandText = batches[i];
                       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = batches[i];
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Filip Cordas. Although this isn't marked as an answer this helped me like a charm ! We had large amount of scripts where the BatchTerminator was mentioned different ways like combinations of upper and lower cases (go, Go, GO etc) and maximum times had trailing or leading spaces with it which caused a big problem for execution via c#.... 

Thank you !!

Comment: @DipakRiswadkar Yes locked at this question a few times and none of the answers provided meet my needs, so looked at EF implementation looked good so I posted the answer.

Comment: Awesome answer, it works like a charm, thanks a lot

Comment: @Really should report it to Entity Framework team as well. As I said this was just a copy past of with little modifications.

Answer (score 6):

The "GO" batch separator keyword is actually used by SQL Management Studio itself, so that it knows where to terminate the batches it is sending to the server, and it is not passed to SQL server. You can even change the keyword in Management Studio, should you so desire.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Blorgbeard's solution.

```
foreach (var sqlBatch in commandText.Split(new[] { "GO" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
   sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlBatch;
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: new[] { "GO", "Go", "go" }

Comment: new[] { "GO", "Go", "go", "gO" }

Comment: Works as long as you have no other use for the two letters in your code, like GOTO-Statements or comments.

Comment: new[] { "GO --DELIMITER" }

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to install SMO objects you can use gplex tool (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892349/1278118))

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use SMO, for example because you need to be cross-platform, you can also use the ScriptSplitter class from SubText.

[Here's](https://github.com/ststeiger/ScriptSplitter) the implementation in C# & VB.NET

Usage:

```
    string strSQL = @"
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
GO
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views
";

    foreach(string Script in new Subtext.Scripting.ScriptSplitter(strSQL ))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Script);
    }
```

If you have problems with multiline c-style comments, remove the comments with regex:

```
static string RemoveCstyleComments(string strInput)
{
    string strPattern = @"/[*][\w\d\s]+[*]/";
    //strPattern = @"/\*.*?\*/"; // Doesn't work
    //strPattern = "/\\*.*?\\*/"; // Doesn't work
    //strPattern = @"/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/ "; // Doesn't work
    //strPattern = @"/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/ "; // Doesn't work

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462843/improving-fixing-a-regex-for-c-style-block-comments
    strPattern = @"/\*(?>(?:(?>[^*]+)|\*(?!/))*)\*/";  // Works !

    string strOutput = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strInput, strPattern, string.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
    return strOutput;
} // End Function RemoveCstyleComments
```

Removing single-line comments is here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842991/regex-to-remove-single-line-sql-comments
```

Comment: does this class consider `/*  Go  */` case?

Comment: @cMinor: Not in the splitter, but you can remove multiline-comments with regex before you split.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem, and I could not find any other way but splitting the single SQL operation in separate files, then executing all of them in sequence.

Obviously the problem is not with lists of DML commands, they can be executed without GO in between; different story with DDL (create, alter, drop...)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go the SMO route you can search and replace "GO" for ";" and the query as you would. Note that soly the the last result set will be returned.

Comment: They are executing ExecuteNonQuery.  This is by far the easier way.

Comment: Using "GO" will allow you to define the same variables again in the next command in the batch.   Placing a semicolon will not do that.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished this today by loading my SQL from a text file into one string. I then used the string Split function to separate the string into individual commands which were then sent to the server individually.  Simples :)

Just realised that you need to split on \nGO just in case the letters GO appear in any of your table names etc.  Guess I was lucky there!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use SMO (which is better than the solution below, but i want to give an alternative...) you can split your query with this function.

It is:

- Comment proof (example --GO or /* GO */)
- Only works on a new line, just as in SSMS (example /* test /* GO works and select 1 as go not
- String proof (example print 'no go ')

  ```
  private List<string> SplitScriptGo(string script)
  {
      var result = new List<string>();
      int pos1 = 0;
      int pos2 = 0;
      bool whiteSpace = true;
      bool emptyLine = true;
      bool inStr = false;
      bool inComment1 = false;
      bool inComment2 = false;

      while (true)
      {
          while (pos2 < script.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(script[pos2]))
          {
              if (script[pos2] == '\r' || script[pos2] == '\n')
              {
                  emptyLine = true;
                  inComment1 = false;
              }

              pos2++;
          }

          if (pos2 == script.Length)
              break;

          bool min2 = (pos2 + 1) < script.Length;
          bool min3 = (pos2 + 2) < script.Length;

          if (!inStr && !inComment2 && min2 && script.Substring(pos2, 2) == "--")
              inComment1 = true;

          if (!inStr && !inComment1 && min2 && script.Substring(pos2, 2) == "/*")
              inComment2 = true;

          if (!inComment1 && !inComment2 && script[pos2] == '\'')
              inStr = !inStr;

          if (!inStr && !inComment1 && !inComment2 && emptyLine
              && (min2 && script.Substring(pos2, 2).ToLower() == "go")
              && (!min3 || char.IsWhiteSpace(script[pos2 + 2]) || script.Substring(pos2 + 2, 2) == "--" || script.Substring(pos2 + 2, 2) == "/*"))
          {
              if (!whiteSpace)
                  result.Add(script.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1));

              whiteSpace = true;
              emptyLine = false;
              pos2 += 2;
              pos1 = pos2;
          }
          else
          {
              pos2++;
              whiteSpace = false;

              if (!inComment2)
                  emptyLine = false;
          }

          if (!inStr && inComment2 && pos2 > 1 && script.Substring(pos2 - 2, 2) == "*/")
              inComment2 = false;
      }

      if (!whiteSpace)
          result.Add(script.Substring(pos1));

      return result;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in java and I solved it with a bit of logic and regex. I believe the same logic can be applied.First I read from the slq file into memory. Then I apply the following logic. It's pretty much what has been said before however I believe that using regex word bound is safer than expecting a new line char.

```
String pattern = "\\bGO\\b|\\bgo\\b";

String[] splitedSql = sql.split(pattern);
for (String chunk : splitedSql) {
  getJdbcTemplate().update(chunk);
}
```

This basically splits the sql string into an array of sql strings. The regex is basically to detect full 'go' words either lower case or upper case. Then you execute the different querys sequentially.

Comment: Careful: how will you split this? `insert into books values ('1478355824', 'An Introduction To Programming in Go (paperback)', 9.00)`

Comment: Good point :-) My situation didn't have inserts of data. Was just creating tables, stored procedures and functions. The word bound was more useful in my particular case because it also took care of 'go' in last line.

Answer (score 1):

use the following method to split the string and execute batch by batch

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace RegExTrial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sql = String.Empty;
            string path=@"D:\temp\sample.sql";
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path)) {
                sql = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }            
            //Select any GO (ignore case) that starts with at least 
            //one white space such as tab, space,new line, verticle tab etc
            string pattern="[\\s](?i)GO(?-i)";

            Regex matcher = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
            int start = 0;
            int end = 0;
            Match batch=matcher.Match(sql);
            while (batch.Success) {
                end = batch.Index;
                string batchQuery = sql.Substring(start, end - start).Trim();
                //execute the batch
                ExecuteBatch(batchQuery);
                start = end + batch.Length;
                batch = matcher.Match(sql,start);
            }

        }

        private static void ExecuteBatch(string command)
        { 
            //execute your query here
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid third parties, regexes, memory overheads and fast work with large scripts I created my own stream-based parser. It

- checks syntax before
- can recognize comments with -- or /**/

  ```
  -- some commented text
   /*
  drop table Users;
  GO
     */
  ```
- can recognize string literals with ' or "

  ```
  set @s =
      'create table foo(...);
      GO
      create index ...';
  ```
- preserves LF and CR formatting
- preserves comments block in object bodies (stored procedures, views etc.)
- and other constructions such as

  ```
        gO -- commented text
  ```

### How to use

```
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DATABASE-NAME;Data Source=SERVER-NAME"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            int rowsAffected = SqlStatementReader.ExecuteSqlFile(
                "C:\\target-sql-script.sql",
                connection,
                // Don't forget to use the correct file encoding!!!
                Encoding.Default,
                // Indefinitely (sec)
                0
            );
        }
    }
    // implement your handlers
    catch (SqlStatementReader.SqlBadSyntaxException) { }
    catch (SqlException) { }
    catch (Exception) { }
```

### Stream-based SQL script reader

```
class SqlStatementReader
{
    public class SqlBadSyntaxException : Exception
    {
        public SqlBadSyntaxException(string description) : base(description) { }
        public SqlBadSyntaxException(string description, int line) : base(OnBase(description, line, null)) { }
        public SqlBadSyntaxException(string description, int line, string filePath) : base(OnBase(description, line, filePath)) { }
        private static string OnBase(string description, int line, string filePath)
        {
            if (filePath == null)
                return string.Format("Line: {0}. {1}", line, description);
            else
                return string.Format("File: {0}\r\nLine: {1}. {2}", filePath, line, description);
        }
    }

    enum SqlScriptChunkTypes
    {
        InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier = 0,
        BracketIdentifier = 1,
        QuotIdentifierOrLiteral = 2,
        DblQuotIdentifierOrLiteral = 3,
        CommentLine = 4,
        CommentMultiline = 5,
    }

    StreamReader _sr = null;
    string _filePath = null;
    int _lineStart = 1;
    int _lineEnd = 1;
    bool _isNextChar = false;
    char _nextChar = '\0';

    public SqlStatementReader(StreamReader sr)
    {
        if (sr == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("StreamReader can't be null.");

        if (sr.BaseStream is FileStream)
            _filePath = ((FileStream)sr.BaseStream).Name;

        _sr = sr;
    }

    public SqlStatementReader(StreamReader sr, string filePath)
    {
        if (sr == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("StreamReader can't be null.");

        _sr = sr;
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public int LineStart { get { return _lineStart; } }
    public int LineEnd { get { return _lineEnd == 1 ? _lineEnd : _lineEnd - 1; } }

    public void LightSyntaxCheck()
    {
        while (ReadStatementInternal(true) != null) ;
    }

    public string ReadStatement()
    {
        for (string s = ReadStatementInternal(false); s != null; s = ReadStatementInternal(false))
        {
            // skip empty
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (s[i])
                {
                    case ' ': continue;
                    case '\t': continue;
                    case '\r': continue;
                    case '\n': continue;
                    default:
                        return s;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    string ReadStatementInternal(bool syntaxCheck)
    {
        if (_isNextChar == false && _sr.EndOfStream)
            return null;

        StringBuilder allLines = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        SqlScriptChunkTypes nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
        SqlScriptChunkTypes currentChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
        char ch = '\0';
        int lineCounter = 0;
        int nextLine = 0;
        int currentLine = 0;
        bool nextCharHandled = false;
        bool foundGO;
        int go = 1;

        while (ReadChar(out ch))
        {
            if (nextCharHandled == false)
            {
                currentChunk = nextChunk;
                currentLine = nextLine;

                switch (currentChunk)
                {
                    case SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier:

                        if (ch == '[')
                        {
                            currentChunk = nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.BracketIdentifier;
                            currentLine = nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        else if (ch == '"')
                        {
                            currentChunk = nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.DblQuotIdentifierOrLiteral;
                            currentLine = nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        else if (ch == '\'')
                        {
                            currentChunk = nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.QuotIdentifierOrLiteral;
                            currentLine = nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        else if (ch == '-' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '-'))
                        {
                            nextCharHandled = true;
                            currentChunk = nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.CommentLine;
                            currentLine = nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        else if (ch == '/' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '*'))
                        {
                            nextCharHandled = true;
                            currentChunk = nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.CommentMultiline;
                            currentLine = nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        else if (ch == ']')
                        {
                            throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Incorrect syntax near ']'.", _lineEnd + lineCounter, _filePath);
                        }
                        else if (ch == '*' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '/'))
                        {
                            throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Incorrect syntax near '*'.", _lineEnd + lineCounter, _filePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case SqlScriptChunkTypes.CommentLine:

                        if (ch == '\r' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '\n'))
                        {
                            nextCharHandled = true;
                            currentChunk = nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
                            currentLine = nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                        {
                            currentChunk = nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
                            currentLine = nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        break;

                    case SqlScriptChunkTypes.CommentMultiline:

                        if (ch == '*' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '/'))
                        {
                            nextCharHandled = true;
                            nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
                            nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        else if (ch == '/' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '*'))
                        {
                            throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Missing end comment mark '*/'.", _lineEnd + currentLine, _filePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case SqlScriptChunkTypes.BracketIdentifier:

                        if (ch == ']')
                        {
                            nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
                            nextLine = lineCounter;
                        }
                        break;

                    case SqlScriptChunkTypes.DblQuotIdentifierOrLiteral:

                        if (ch == '"')
                        {
                            if (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '"')
                            {
                                nextCharHandled = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
                                nextLine = lineCounter;
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case SqlScriptChunkTypes.QuotIdentifierOrLiteral:

                        if (ch == '\'')
                        {
                            if (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '\'')
                            {
                                nextCharHandled = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                nextChunk = SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier;
                                nextLine = lineCounter;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
                nextCharHandled = false;

            foundGO = false;
            if (currentChunk == SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier || go >= 5 || (go == 4 && currentChunk == SqlScriptChunkTypes.CommentLine))
            {
                // go = 0 - break, 1 - begin of the string, 2 - spaces after begin of the string, 3 - G or g, 4 - O or o, 5 - spaces after GO, 6 - line comment after valid GO
                switch (go)
                {
                    case 0:
                        if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')
                            go = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')
                            go = 2;
                        else if (ch == 'G' || ch == 'g')
                            go = 3;
                        else if (ch != '\n' && ch != '\r')
                            go = 0;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (ch == 'G' || ch == 'g')
                            go = 3;
                        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                            go = 1;
                        else if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t')
                            go = 0;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (ch == 'O' || ch == 'o')
                            go = 4;
                        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                            go = 1;
                        else
                            go = 0;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (ch == '\r' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '\n'))
                            go = 5;
                        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                            foundGO = true;
                        else if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')
                            go = 5;
                        else if (ch == '-' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '-'))
                            go = 6;
                        else
                            go = 0;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (ch == '\r' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '\n'))
                            go = 5;
                        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                            foundGO = true;
                        else if (ch == '-' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '-'))
                            go = 6;
                        else if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t')
                            throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing go.", _lineEnd + lineCounter, _filePath);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (ch == '\r' && (_isNextChar && _nextChar == '\n'))
                            go = 6;
                        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                            foundGO = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        go = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
                go = 0;

            if (foundGO)
            {
                if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')
                {
                    ++lineCounter;
                }
                // clear GO
                string s = line.Append(ch).ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    switch (s[i])
                    {
                        case ' ': continue;
                        case '\t': continue;
                        case '\r': continue;
                        case '\n': continue;
                        default:
                            _lineStart = _lineEnd;
                            _lineEnd += lineCounter;
                            return allLines.Append(s.Substring(0, i)).ToString();
                    }
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }

            // accumulate by string
            if (ch == '\r' && (_isNextChar == false || _nextChar != '\n'))
            {
                ++lineCounter;
                if (syntaxCheck == false)
                    allLines.Append(line.Append('\r').ToString());
                line.Clear();
            }
            else if (ch == '\n')
            {
                ++lineCounter;
                if (syntaxCheck == false)
                    allLines.Append(line.Append('\n').ToString());
                line.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                if (syntaxCheck == false)
                    line.Append(ch);
            }
        }

        // this is the end of the stream, return it without GO, if GO exists
        switch (currentChunk)
        {
            case SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier:
            case SqlScriptChunkTypes.CommentLine:
                break;
            case SqlScriptChunkTypes.CommentMultiline:
                if (nextChunk != SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier)
                    throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Missing end comment mark '*/'.", _lineEnd + currentLine, _filePath);
                break;
            case SqlScriptChunkTypes.BracketIdentifier:
                if (nextChunk != SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier)
                    throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Unclosed quotation mark [.", _lineEnd + currentLine, _filePath);
                break;
            case SqlScriptChunkTypes.DblQuotIdentifierOrLiteral:
                if (nextChunk != SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier)
                    throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Unclosed quotation mark \".", _lineEnd + currentLine, _filePath);
                break;
            case SqlScriptChunkTypes.QuotIdentifierOrLiteral:
                if (nextChunk != SqlScriptChunkTypes.InstructionOrUnquotedIdentifier)
                    throw new SqlBadSyntaxException("Unclosed quotation mark '.", _lineEnd + currentLine, _filePath);
                break;
        }

        if (go >= 4)
        {
            string s = line.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (s[i])
                {
                    case ' ': continue;
                    case '\t': continue;
                    case '\r': continue;
                    case '\n': continue;
                    default:
                        _lineStart = _lineEnd;
                        _lineEnd += lineCounter + 1;
                        return allLines.Append(s.Substring(0, i)).ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        _lineStart = _lineEnd;
        _lineEnd += lineCounter + 1;
        return allLines.Append(line.ToString()).ToString();
    }

    bool ReadChar(out char ch)
    {
        if (_isNextChar)
        {
            ch = _nextChar;
            if (_sr.EndOfStream)
                _isNextChar = false;
            else
                _nextChar = Convert.ToChar(_sr.Read());
            return true;
        }
        else if (_sr.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(_sr.Read());
            if (_sr.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                _isNextChar = true;
                _nextChar = Convert.ToChar(_sr.Read());
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ch = '\0';
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int ExecuteSqlFile(string filePath, SqlConnection connection, Encoding fileEncoding, int commandTimeout)
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // Simple syntax check (you can comment out these two lines below)
            new SqlStatementReader(new StreamReader(fs, fileEncoding)).LightSyntaxCheck();
            fs.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Read statements without GO
            SqlStatementReader rd = new SqlStatementReader(new StreamReader(fs, fileEncoding));
            string stmt;
            while ((stmt = rd.ReadStatement()) != null)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = stmt;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (i > 0)
                        rowsAffected += i;
                }
            }
        }
        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same issue and eventually just solved it by a simple string replace, replacing the word GO with a semi-colon (;)

All seems to be working fine while executing scripts with in-line comments, block comments, and GO commands

```
public static bool ExecuteExternalScript(string filePath)
{
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath))
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConnStr))
    {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // replace GO with semi-colon
            if (line == "GO")
                sql.Append(";");
            // remove inline comments
            else if (line.IndexOf("--") > -1)
                sql.AppendFormat(" {0} ", line.Split(new string[] { "--" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]);
            // just the line as it is
            else
                sql.AppendFormat(" {0} ", line);
        }
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It won't work for DDL commands, which need to be in their own batch. E.g. create/alter table et al

Comment: Also, you seem to removing comments for no reason.. Which would break any strings containing `--`, for example.

Comment: Hi Blorgbeard - SQL Server 2012 seems to be handling DDL statements OK. The scripts I was using were to allow me to rebuild a whole database structure, wiping the current structure, building tables, adding indexes etc. I thought ; also finished a batch?

Comment: Also the removal of comments was because this will produce a single line of SQL, any SQL after the comment would therefore be commented out, but I take your point if there was a string that contained -- that wasn't a comment.

Comment: Ah ok, just looked it up: "CREATE DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE RULE, CREATE SCHEMA, CREATE TRIGGER, and CREATE VIEW statements cannot be combined with other statements in a batch. The CREATE statement must start the batch. All other statements that follow in that batch will be interpreted as part of the definition of the first CREATE statement.
A table cannot be changed and then the new columns referenced in the same batch."

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `;` at the end of each statement as it worked for me.
Really don't know if there are any drawbacks to it.

Comment: Not really. For example, you must have `CREATE FUNCTION` at the start of each statement. Terminating the last one with `;` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most elegant solution I could find.

Let's say your SQL script containing `GO` statements is in a file `script.sql`.

You can do:

```
$query = ((Get-Content -Raw "script.sql") -replace '([\s\n]*)GO([\s\n]+)','$1$2')
```

This will remove all GO statements without removing other occurences of the string `go` anywhere else (according to my tests).

You can then do:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection                
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = <your_connection_string>

$SqlConnection.Open()
   
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $query
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

which should normally work without issues.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still having the problem. You could use official Microsoft SMO

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-2017

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
  server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything over the top voted, accepted answer, which also suggests SMO (posted 10 years ago!).

Answer (score -4):

Too difficult :)

Create  array of strings str[] replacing GO with ",@" :

```
            string[] str ={
                @"
USE master;
",@"


CREATE DATABASE " +con_str_initdir+ @";
",@"
-- Verify the database files and sizes
--SELECT name, size, size*1.0/128 AS [Size in MBs] 
--SELECT name 
--FROM sys.master_files
--WHERE name = N'" + con_str_initdir + @"';
--GO

USE " + con_str_initdir + @";
",@"

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
",@"
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
",@"

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Customers]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
",@"



SET ANSI_NULLS ON
",@"
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
",@"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[GOODS]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GOODS](
    [GoodsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GoodsName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [GoodsPrice] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GOODS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GoodsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
",@"
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
",@"
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
",@"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Orders]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
",@"
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
",@"
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
",@"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[OrderDetails]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails](
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GoodsID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderID] ASC,
    [GoodsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
",@"

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
",@"
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
",@"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[InsertCustomers]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomers]
 @CustomerName nvarchar(50),
 @Identity int OUT
AS
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName) VALUES(@CustomerName)
SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

' 
END
",@"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_Orders_Customers]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Orders]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customers] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
",@"
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customers]
",@"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_OrderDetails_GOODS]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[OrderDetails]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetails_GOODS] FOREIGN KEY([GoodsID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[GOODS] ([GoodsID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
",@"
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetails_GOODS]
",@"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_OrderDetails_Orders]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[OrderDetails]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetails_Orders] FOREIGN KEY([OrderID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
",@"
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetails_Orders]


                "};


            for(int i =0; i<str.Length;i++)     
            {
                myCommand.CommandText=str[i];
                try
                {
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SystemException ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error   "+ee.ToString());
                }

            }
```

That's all, enjoy.