# Javascript RegEx Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to find below comment block(s) with javascript/jquery regex:

```
  /*

    some description here

  */
```

It may even look like:

```
  /* some description here
  */
```

Or

```
  /* some description here */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this one could help you

```
/(\/\*[.\S\s]*?\*\/)/g
```

seem to be working

http://jsfiddle.net/WDhZP/

Answer (score 2):

With php I think it would be :

```
$pattern='/\/\*.*?/*///';
```

or

$pattern='`/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/`';

chk this out

[Improving/Fixing a Regex for C style block comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462843/improving-fixing-a-regex-for-c-style-block-comments)

This is to match empty comment blocks :

```
^\s+/\*{1,}\n(^\s*\*{1,}\s*)+\*{1,}/
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account carriage returns or line feeds. I think the asker needs to be able to detect block comments with multiple lines. However, it does work for one-liners.

Comment: @Levi Hackwith it matches his last requirement he said OR didn't say AND :D

Comment: Didn't the question explicitly say Javascript?

Comment: @Pointy yes, instead of $pattern he should use var pattern = myPattern.match()

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = myString.match(/\/\*([\w\W]*)\*\//)
```

If `match !== null`, `match[0]` will contain the comment, and `match[1]` will contain the comment without the comment delimiters.

edit: it's multiline now ;)

Comment: Use `[d\D]` instead of `.`. That will match newlines. At least it does so in .NET =)

Comment: Aren't both "*" and "/" not word characters?  Thus won't they both match "\W"?  Indeed, isn't "[\w\W]" pretty much the same as "."?

Comment: `.` doesn't match `\n` but `\W` does. Worse, it looks like you can't match `.` with anything else in a `[]`. So `[.\n]` is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an actual Javascript answer:

```
var commentRegex = /\/\*([^/]|\/[^*])*\*\//;
```

If you need a version that checks to see whether an *entire* string is a comment:

```
var completeCommentRegex = /^\/\*([^/]|\/[^*])*\*\/$/m;
```

Explanation: the regex matches a leading `/*`, followed by any number of either individual characters other than "/", or "/" followed by anything not an asterisk, and then finally the closing `*/`.  The "m" flag in the second version ensures that embedded newlines won't mess up the "^" and "$" anchors.

Finally, if you actually want the comment text, you'd add an appropriate parenthesized block in there (after the `/*` and before the `*/`).