# Differentiating SQL strings from comments

Tags: java, sql, regex, string, comments

I have files of SQL code that I want to beautify, and I'm having trouble with differentiating between whether a certain line/part of the code is a String or a comment.

My current process is I do a Pattern/Matcher search through the file and pull out the strings with the regex `N?'([']{2}|[^'])*+'(?!')` and the comments with `\s*--.*?\n|/\*.*?\*/`, and put them in their respective storage arrays to avoid formatting them.

EXAMPLES:

`WHERE y = 'STRING'` -> `WHERE y = THIS_IS_A_STRING` and `strings[0] = 'STRING'`

`SELECT x --do not format`-> `SELECT x THIS_IS_A_COMMENT` and `comments[0] = --do not format`

After beautifying everything, I then go through and search for `THIS_IS_A_STRING` and `THIS_IS_A_COMMENT` and restore their respective values from the arrays.

The problem I'm running into is if a comment has an apostrophe in it, or if a SQL string has double dashes in it. I can fix one problem, but it causes the other, depending on whether I choose to preserve strings or comments first.

For example:

`--Don't format this` with preserving strings going first will match `'nt format this` all the way through to the next `'`, (due to the ability to have multiline strings).

On the flip side, if I choose to preserve comments first:

`SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = '--THIS_IS_AS_STRING--'`, it will detect the `--` and store everything until the next newline into the comments array.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

**EDIT: I know I should probably do this with a SQL parser, but I have been working on this with mainly regex and this is the last step I need to finishing**

Comment: This is a job for a SQL parser, not regex.

Answer (score 0):

I made this reqexp:

```
/^(([^\\'"\-]+|\-[^\\'"\-]|\\.)+|-?'([^\\']+|\\.)+'|-?"([^\\"]+|\\.)+")+\-\-[^\n]+/
```

To match thouse Rules for SQL comments

- a comment row ends with `--`, comment, and row break.
- before the comment we can have:

  - any chars except `\'"-`
  - a `-` if not followed by any of `\'"-`
  - a `\` followed by any character including `\'"-`
  - a pair of `'` that dosn't have a `'` between them, unless its have a odd number of `\` inforont of it.
  - a pair of `"` that dosn't have a `"` between them, unless its have a odd number of `\` inforont of it.
  - the pairs can have a single `-` inforont of them, but not 2

did i miss somthing?

Answer (score 0):

This link may help:
[Java Regex find/replace pattern in SQL comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753836/java-regex-find-replace-pattern-in-sql-comments)

I paste the code here

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:/\\*[^;]*?\\*/)|(?:--[^;]*?$)", Pattern.DOTALL |    Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
        // match start: regexMatcher.start()
        // match end: regexMatcher.end()
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

I would replace the comment first, and then use the replaced string as input for string regex. This way the regex will not confuse string and comment.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize that Song is looking for a regex solution for this problem, I would like to point out that SQL is not regular (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5639859/2503659), hence no regex solution exists.

With that said, I think others have given good solutions for common scenarios.