# What is a regular expression for finding lines with uncommented Java code?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on a simple Ruby program that should count of the lines of text in a Java file that contain actual Java code. The line gets counted even if it has comments in it, so basically only lines that are **just** comments won't get counted.

I was thinking of using a regular expression to approach this problem. My program will just iterate line by line and compare it to a "regexp", like:

```
while line = file.gets
    if line =~ regex
        count+=1
    end
end
```

I'm not sure what regexp format to use for that, though. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not that simple. `/*` Comments can span multiple lines.

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, would it work if I had two separate regex, one of which could check if a comment spanned multiple lines and read additional lines accordingly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/462843/897024 for multiline comments.

Comment: Can you use JRuby?  There are plenty of Java parsing libraries available you could read the Java source much more accurately and easily that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the count for "Lines of code" can be a little subjective. Should auto-generated stuff like imports and package name really count? A person usually didn't write it. Does a line with just a closing curly brace count? There's not really any executing logic on that line.

I typically use this regex for counting Java lines of code:

```
^(?![ \s]*\r?\n|import|package|[ \s]*}\r?\n|[ \s]*//|[ \s]*/\*|[ \s]*\*).*\r?\n
```

This will omit:

- Blank lines
- Imports
- Lines with the package name
- Lines with just a }
- Lines with single line comments //
- Opening multi-line comments ((whitespace)/* whatever)
- Continuation of multi-line comments ((whitespace)* whatever)

It will also match against either `\n` or `\r\n` newlines (since your source code could contain either depending on your OS).

While not perfect, it seems to come pretty close to matching against all, what I would consider, "legitimate" lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
file.each_line do |ln|
  # Manage multiline and single line comments.
  # Exclude single line if and only if there isn't code on that line
  next if ln =~ %r{^\s*(//|/\*[^*]*\*/$|$)} or (ln =~ %r{/\*} .. ln =~ %r{\*/})
  count += 1
end
```

There's only a problem with lines that have a multilines comment but also code, for example:

```
someCall(); /* Start comment
this a comment
even this
*/ thisShouldBeCounted();
```

However:

```
imCounted(); // Comment
meToo(); /* comment */
/* comment */ yesImCounted();
// i'm not
/* Nor
we
are
*/
```

---

**EDIT**
The following version is a bit more cumbersome but correctly count all cases.

```
count = 0
comment_start = false
file.each_line do |ln|
  # Manage multiline and single line comments.
  # Exclude single line if and only if there isn't code on that line
  next if ln =~ %r{^\s*(//|/\*[^*]*\*/$|$)} or (ln =~ %r{^\s*/\*} .. ln =~ %r{\*/}) or (comment_start and not ln.include? '*/')
  count += 1 unless comment_start and ln =~ %r{\*/\s*$}
  comment_start = ln.include? '/*'
end
```