# REGEX to remove multiline comments

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, comments, lex, multiline

i've searched quite a lot and the best i created till now to match multiline c comments is:

```
\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/
```

but for a text like this:

```
1. Not a comment
2.
3.Ooops Not a comment /**** A multiline comment **/  Ooops Not a comment
4. Ooops Not a comment /**** A multiline comment **\/
5.  ******  Ooops Not a comment
6.  ***/
7.// A another comment
8.Another not a comment
9.
10. "/*Again not a comment*/"
11.// A line comment at the end of file

The outcome looks like this: 

1. Not a comment
2.
3.Ooops Not a comment "
11.// A line comment at the end of file
```

Can someone explain my mistake and give me the correct one? thank you!

Full code:
[spoiler]

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *fout;
%}

%%
\/\*(.|\n)*?\*\/
%%
void main( int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if ( argc < 3 )
    {
        printf("\nError!!! Missing Command line arguments");
        printf("\nUsage exe <inputfile> <outputfile>");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        fout = fopen(argv[2],"w");
        yyout = fout;
        yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        yylex();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

[/spoiler]

Comment: Duplicate. See: [Improving/Fixing a Regex for C style block comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3945705/433790)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `?` to make it non-greedy: `\/\*(.|\n)*?\*\/`.

Matches:

1. `/**** A multiline comment **/`
2. `/**** A multiline comment **\/ 5.  ******  Ooops Not a comment 6.  ***/`
3. `/*Again not a comment*/`

If these matches are not correct please explain better what exactly *should* be matched.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) . Nothing changed, tt gives me the same outcome. By the way it's the first time i see putting an ? after an *.

Comment: Yes tenub these are exactly what i want it to match but for some reason it doesn't :/

Comment: What about changing to `/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/`? Forward slashes don't necessarily need escaping unless it's your RegEx delimiter.

Comment: I tried your expression \/\*(.|\n)*?\*\/  on an online regex tester and it was correct. Maybe regexs are different on different situations? I am using Visual Studio 2008(flex and bison) and i'm running these on a .l file(i have to use this way cause thats what the proffesor demands).The  /\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/ gives Error 1 error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Generating lexical analyser..." Project3 Project3

Comment: What is your full code you're running to implement this RegEx and return matches? Can you edit the original question to include this code?

Comment: What about keeping the `[\r\n]` addition and re-escaping the forward slashes? If it still doesn't work I have no clue. What is your actual goal here though? Do you need to use Visual Studio? Are you trying to extract comments from many text files? Etc.

Comment: i'm sorry i my english aren't the best i don't understand exactly what you mean by "What about keeping the [\r\n] addition and re-escaping the forward slashes?" . Yes i have to use visual studio 2008, And what i'm doing for example in this case is taking as input a text and having as output a text without the multiline comments.

Comment: I mean to try: `\/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*\/`

Comment: nope, does the same thing. thank you for your time :)

Comment: Clearly an issue with Visual Studio implementation of RegEx. Something so trivial should be very easy to successfully match.

Comment: Thats the worst outcome...having to learn so much and knowing that the examples and which i use to understand, might not work on my compiler :/ I really appreciate your help though. Thnx again