# Regular expression for a string that does not start with a /*

Tags: regex, editpad

I use EditPad Pro text editor.
I need read string into code, but I need to ignore ones that start with the label "/*" or tab + /*, for example:

```
/**
 * Light up the dungeon using "claravoyance"
 *
 * memorizes all floor grids too.
**/ 
/** This function returns TRUE if a "line of sight" **/
#include "cave.h"
 (tab here) /* Vertical "knights" */

if (g->multiple_objects) {
  /* Get the "pile" feature instead */
  k_ptr = &k_info[0];
}

put_str("Text inside", hgt - 1, (wid - COL_MAP) / 2);

/* More code*** */
```

I like to return:

```
"Text inside"
```

I have try this (reading [Regular expression for a string that does not start with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence)), but not work for me:

```
^(?! \*/\t).+".*"
```

any help?

**Edit**: I used:

```
^(?!#| |(\t*/)|(/)).+".*"
```

And it return:

```
put_str("Text inside"
```

I'm close to finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EditPad](http://www.editpadpro.com/) obviously supports [variable-length lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) in **pro version 6** and **lite version 7** since it's [flavor is indicated as "JGsoft"](http://www.editpadpro.com/manual/optionregex.html): [Just Great Software regular expression engine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/jgsoft.html).

Knowing this and without the use of [capture groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html), you could combine two variable length [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!^[ \t]*/?[*#][^"\n]*")(?<=^[^"\n]*")[^"]+
```

- `(?<!^[ \t]*/?[*#][^"\n]*")` The negative lookbehind for avoiding the quoted part to be preceded by `[ \t]*/?[*#]` any comments, which could be preceded by any amount of space/tab. Made the `/` optional, as a multi-line comment can also start with `*`.
- `(?<=^[^"\n]*")` The positive lookbehind for assuring, that there's any amount of `[^"\n]`, `characters, that are no quotes or newlines` followed by one quote before.
- `[^"]+` As  supposed to be always balanced quoting, now it should be convenient, to match the `non-quotes` after the first `double-quote` (which is inside the lookbehind)
- If a single `"` may occur in any line (not balanced), change the end: `[^"]+` to `[^"\n]+(?=")`

[image]

Possibly there are different solutions for the problem. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Almost!! I forgot include the code: #include "cave.h", and your solution show me "cave.h", can improve the regexp?

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez So also lines starting with `#` (with optional spaces preceded) should not be taken into account? See updated answer.

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez Thanks for the compliment, also learned new, while thinking of your regex problem :) Great it works out now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/\*.*\*/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|".*?"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/aC4vO4/2)**

[image]

Edit: if you use EditPad then you can use this regex:

```
"[\w\s]+"(?!.*\*/)
```

Comment: I use EditPad Pro text editor, the /\*.*\*/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|".*?" fails.

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez can you check with this example http://regex101.com/r/aC4vO4/3 ?

Comment: In http://regex101.com/ works fine, but in EditPad return more characters, weird. I will wait two days for evaluate.

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez I'll try to find out another answer. Btw, since it works on regex101 maybe you can use it instead of EditPad

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez I think you are looking for this http://regex101.com/r/aC4vO4/4

Comment: I Update the example code for one more real, and regexe101 return to me "claravoyance" and "Text inside", incorrect text. I might use a EditPad because I'm in project of game translation write in C.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach: `^(?!\t*/\*).*?"(.+?)"`

Breakdown:

```
^(?!\t*/\*)  This is a negative lookahead anchored to the beginning of the line, 
             to ensure that there is no `/*` at the beginning (with or 
             without tabs)

.*?"         Next is any amount of characters, up to a double-quote. It's lazy 
             so it stops at the first quote


(.+?)"       This is the capture group for everything between the quotes, again
             lazy so it doesn't slurp other quotes
```

Comment: very close, but return to me: put_str("Text inside"

Comment: You want to look at the capture group only (group 1), not the whole match.