# SQL Scripts from dotnet with transactions

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net, transactions

I have been trying to execute sql scripts from dotnet (C#) but the sql scripts could contain GO statements and I would like to be able to wrap the collection of scripts in a transaction.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/how-do-i-execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands-from-c) question and the accepted answer got me going for handling the GO statements, but if I use a BeginTransaction it throws a **InvalidOperationException** at the "new ServerConnection" line.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(transactionName);
ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
```

I am running this against a SQL 2005 server.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 5):

I found a way, after trying several combinations, the simplest one worked...

Well this is assuming you are using a `TransactionScope` object

```
using (
    var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                                new TransactionOptions
                                                    {
                                                        IsolationLevel =
                                                            IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                                                        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(300)
                                                    }))
{
    sqlServerInstance.ConnectionContext.SqlExecutionModes = SqlExecutionModes.ExecuteAndCaptureSql;
    sqlServerInstance.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = int.MaxValue;

    //This line makes the MAGIC happen =)
    sqlServerInstance.ConnectionContext.SqlConnectionObject.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
    sqlServerInstance.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scriptContent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `BeginTransaction` and `CommitTransaction` methods on the `ServerConnection` instance instead.  I use this without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the transaction after you've attached the `ServerConnection` to the `SqlConnection`'s settings.

Also, what are you using `ServerConnection` for that you can't do from `SqlConnection`?

Comment: GO commands in the SQL scripts are not supported from SqlConnection

Comment: Use Regex.Split to split the script on the GO commands. Execute the batches one at a time on the same connection, with the same transaction.

Comment: OK.  I think you can make a ServerConnection without a SqlConnection, so I'm not sure you need the SqlConnection, nor do you need to start a transaction on it, since you can start a transaction on the ServerConnection after it is made.