# Keywords in SQL script data causing problems when executing programmatically - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, sqlcommand, sql-insert

I'm fairly new to sql and am having a problem with keywords causing havoc in my sql script. I'm trying to execute a list of premade .sql script files in C#. I'm currently reading the file to a string and executing it with command.ExecuteNonQuery(). This works great for most of the scripts, but I'm running into one that inadvertently contains a keyword:

```
INSERT INTO [thetable]
SELECT '123123', 'abcabc', 'I WANT TO GO TO BED'
UNION ALL
SELECT '123124', 'abcdef', 'SOOO TIRED'
```

Essentially, when it hits that GO the command fails.

I am in charge of creating these insert files, so if I need to reformat them in some way then that is possible; however, the data in them is non negotiable. Also, since I am loading them from a file with many rows, parameterization to avoid this stuff doesn't seem feasible either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT** to add info:

To clarify, the actual string is something more like 'ASVFDS4+23eF3da34sddsdf3d3t4g...100charslater...sd5OAyGOsiISIssdsd/sNUIGsdisd354f'. When I try and execute the command, I catch the exception, which says:

```
"Unclosed quotation mark after character string 'ASVFDS4+23eF3da34sddsdf3d3t4g...100charslater...sd5OAy'
```

Note that 5OAy is immediately followed by GOsiIS..., which lead me to believe that the GO is actually being read as a command, causing it to expect an end to the string before that command.

Running .NET 3.5

**EDIT 2**
I also should clarify, I am currently splitting on the actual GO statements and executing the commands individually.

i.e.

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
INSERT INTO [thetable]
SELECT '123123', 'abcabc', 'I WANT TO GO TO BED'
UNION ALL
SELECT '123124', 'abcdef', 'SOOO TIRED'
UNION ALL
...
SELECT '123189', 'abcabc', 'HAD SOME SLEEP'
GO
```

splits, so I execute

```
USE MyDatabase
```

and

```
INSERT INTO [thetable]
SELECT '123123', 'abcabc', 'I WANT TO GO TO BED'
UNION ALL
SELECT '123124', 'abcdef', 'SOOO TIRED'
UNION ALL
...
SELECT '123189', 'abcabc', 'HAD SOME SLEEP'
```

separately. So my issue isn't with actual GO statements, it's with the characters 'GO' appearing in the data string.

**ANSWER**:
The problem is that I've made a terribly dumb mistake. I split on "GO", which splits the command string right in the middle of that parameter where the letters GO appear.

/facepalm

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? I very much doubt that the probelm you are having relates to GO being a keyword at least as it is shown in the sql above. I would guess that it's an apostrophe or something else.

Comment: In some applications `GO` is used as a batch separator. Don't think that `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` recognizes `GO`. You probably have some code in C# that parses your SQL scripts and executes one batch at a time right? There is where you need to look for a way to fix this. If you have coded that yourself and have control over the generation of the script files you can change your code to only trigger a new batch when `GO` is by itself on a single line.

Comment: What database are you using?  If it's SQL Server and it's the developer edition or above.  Try running SQL Profiler to see the SQL that is being run on the server.

Comment: Agree with Andrew: look at the actual SQL being executed, and make sure it's "clean" (via SQL Profiler). @Mikael-Eriksson - I use the  .ExecuteNonQuery() method in .NET specifically to deal with the GO keyword - it recognizes it as a batch separator. MarnBeast - ideally, we need more info. Post your C# code as well!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/how-do-i-execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands-from-c

Comment: I just figured it out, dumb mistake, I've edited it into the question. Thanks a lot for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recognise the GO yourself, and use it to split the file up into batches, then execute each one individually.

Use a regex something like m/^\s+GO\s+$/i to recognise the GO lines.

Comment: What's funny is I was actually doing this, using
    .Split(new string[]{"GO"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
This worked more effectively than I anticipated, as I realized that it split the aforementioned string field in the script where it saw the letters GO. Thus, in my list of command strings returned from .Split, one of the commands was split in half in the middle of the string field. Whoops. The problem was fixed after changed it to 
    .Split(new string[]{"\r\nGO"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to parse any Sql scripts with comments and string values with 'go' ("smth go smth") and etc. you can use [gplex](http://gplex.codeplex.com/) tool. Gplex rules for sql script parsing:

```
%namespace LexScanner
%option verbose, summary, noparser, unicode

%x QUOTE
%x COMMENT

%{
    static string line = "";
    static List<string> butch = new List<string>();
    enum TokenType {
        SL_COMMENT,
        ML_COMMENT,
        STRING,
        WORD,
        OTHER,
        ending
    };
%}

dotchr [^\r\n] 
eol (\r\n?|\n)
%%
\-\-[^\n]*$             { add(yytext, TokenType.SL_COMMENT); }

\/\*                    { add(yytext, TokenType.ML_COMMENT); BEGIN(COMMENT); }
<COMMENT>\*\/           { add(yytext, TokenType.ML_COMMENT); BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<COMMENT>[^\*]+         { add(yytext, TokenType.ML_COMMENT); }
<COMMENT>\*             { add(yytext, TokenType.ML_COMMENT); }

\'                      { add(yytext, TokenType.STRING); BEGIN(QUOTE); }
<QUOTE>\'\'             { add(yytext, TokenType.STRING); }
<QUOTE>[^\']+           { add(yytext, TokenType.STRING); }
<QUOTE>\'               { add(yytext, TokenType.STRING); BEGIN(INITIAL); }

[gG][oO]                { push(); }

[a-zA-Z0-9]+            { add(yytext, TokenType.WORD); }
.                       { add(yytext, TokenType.OTHER); }
\r?\n                   { add(yytext, TokenType.OTHER); }
<<EOF>>                 { push(); }
%%
```

Then you generate C# class and use it.

**EDIT:**
Some more comments how to use it.
Functions `add(string text, TokenType token)` and `push()` - what to do with parsed string.
add() function collects parsed strings between GO keywords and writes results to output file (just to control):

```
private void add(string text, TokenType token)
{
    //write to the file for output control (for test only)
    using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\temp.txt", true))
    {
        str.WriteLine(token + " : " + text); 
    }
    line += text;
}
```

push() collects butch strings for execution:

```
private void push()
{
    //write to the file for output control (for test only)
    using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\butch.txt", true))
    {
        str.WriteLine("GO: " + line); 
    }

    butch.Add(line);
    line = "";
}
```

To use this class from C# code your should specify entry point. For example:

```
 public static List<string> ParseFile(String fileToParse)
 {
     int tok;
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner();
     scnr.SetSource(fileToParse, 0);
     do {
             tok = scnr.yylex();
         } while (tok > (int)Tokens.EOF);
     return butch;
 }
```

Or define a Main function to use it as standalone application.

All the above code should be placed in the .lex file. 
The file sqlparser.cs is created by invoking from command line:

```
gplex sqlparser.lex
```

Gplex has a good documentation and examples how to use it.

Comment: could you please give more details (add, push methods) and how to use this from C#, this is definitely the way to go, but I am not an expert at all with Lex... Thanks a lot!