# How can I use a script to perform DDL against a SQL database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have previously used the following script which works fine:

```
    public const string application =
@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application ON
INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name, ModifiedDate) VALUES (1, 'x', getdate() );
INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name, ModifiedDate) VALUES (2, 'y', getdate() );
INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name, ModifiedDate) VALUES (3, 'z', getdate() );
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application OFF
DBCC CHECKIDENT( 'Application', RESEED )";
```

Now I would like to execute DDL but I am getting an error message:

```
    public const string dropCreate =
        @"
        GO
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount] DROP CONSTRAINT [TestAccount_Application]
        GO
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount]
        GO
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO        
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO  
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount](
            [TestAccountId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [Name] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
            [ApplicationId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
            [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [TestAccountId] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [TestAccount_Application] FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Application] ([ApplicationId])
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        GO       
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount] CHECK CONSTRAINT [TestAccount_Application]
        GO";
}

   HResult=-2146232060
   Message=Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

Is it possible for me to execute DDL from C#. The code I am using looks like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TestAccountSQL.dropCreate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GO` is not a SQL keyword; it's interpreted by SQL Server Management Studio.

You need to send each batch as a separate `ExecuteSql` call, or use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO).

See [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/how-do-i-execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands-from-c) for some help with this.

Comment: Is it also possible for me to just end the lines with a semicolon and remove the "go" statements