# Syntax Error, but Copy/Pasted Query Text Works in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sqlexception, verbatim-string

I am having an issue generating a SQL query using C#.  To troubleshoot, I made the button that executes the query also display the query text in a textbox on the form.  What's perplexing is that I get an error saying "Incorrect syntax near 'IF'" when the program tries to execute the query, but if I copy/paste the query from the textbox to SSMS it works fine.

The variable that stores the query looks like:

```
string myQuery = @"  
SELECT DISTINCT filter.id_column INTO #temp1  
FROM MasterDB.dbo.filter filter  
LEFT JOIN ClientDB.dbo.codes codetable  
ON filter.id_column=codetable.id_column  
WHERE codetable.name IS NULL  

DECLARE @code_id1 INT;  
SET @code_id1 = (SELECT MAX(code_num) FROM ClientDB.dbo.codes)+1  
EXEC('ALTER TABLE #temp1 ADD tempID INT IDENTITY(' + @code_id1 + ',1)')  
GO  

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp1)>0  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @code_id2 INT;  
SET @code_id2 = (SELECT MAX(tempID) FROM #temp1)+1  
UPDATE ClientDB.dbo.track  
SET next=@code_id2 WHERE [trackname]='account'  
END";
```

The C# code to populate the textbox with the query text and then run the query looks like:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(HostConnStr))  
using (SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())  
{  
    myCommand.CommandText = myQuery;   
    this.textBox1.Text = myCommand.CommandText;  
    myConnection.Open();  
    try { myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); }  
    catch (SqlException s) { MessageBox.Show(s.ToString()); }  
    myConnection.Close();  
}
```

**Does anyone know why the query text can be copied to SSMS and run fine, but throws a SQL exception when executed from C#?  And how do I make the query run?**

Critique on the query design will be appreciated, but I am more concerned with simply getting the query to execute since it does what I need it to do as-is.

EDIT:  This may be a duplicate (I was thrown off by the error being near 'IF' when it appears that 'GO' is the problem, so my searches were in the wrong direction.  However, I am still not sure that the answers provided in similar questions will work since I am under the impression that splitting the query into multiple commands will fail due to the later part of the query referencing a temporary table in the earlier part (will the temporary table not become unavailable after the first command is finished?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a large SQL script (with GO commands)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `GO` statement. You can replace it with `;` in most instances.

In TSQL it's OK to have multiple statements separated by `GO`. In the ADO.NET version you can't do this.

The way to do this would be spilt the string on the GO and execute each independently. Such as [this example](https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/c-executing-batch-t-sql-scripts-with-go-statements/),

```
string scriptText = @"...."

//split the script on "GO" commands
string[] splitter = new string[] { "\r\nGO\r\n" };
string[] commandTexts = scriptText.Split(splitter,  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string commandText in commandTexts)
{
  //execute commandText
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the query work without the GO statement?  If I'm not mistaken the query will not function as intended without it (correct me if I'm wrong) EDIT: If I split the string after the GO statement, will I not lose my temporary table, which gets referenced in the section that follows the GO?

Comment: Try using a ; instead of the GO but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: I believe that using the semicolon has done the trick- thanks!  If you don't mind putting that option in your answer then I'll go ahead and mark it as accepted