# Establishing a new SQL Connection after creating a database in a server

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

Please pardon me for my English grammar.

I'm currently coding a system and I was wondering if you could establish a new connection after you created a database in a server.

This is the Connection String:

```
Dim DBCon As SqlConnection = New SQLConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\DbLocal;Integrated Security=True")
```

If I want to create a database I use a command - the database name is bounded after a textbox, it goes like:

```
Dim dbName As String = txtdbName.Text
myCommand = "CREATE database " & dbName
```

The database gets created, but after I start a query that creates a table - the table does not save in the created database. So with my beginner skills in VB.Net and MSSQL, I deduced it was because of my Connection String, so I tried messing with it:

```
Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\DbLocal;Database=" & dbName & ";Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
```

I wrote the above code before the create a table query, but after I run it, the tables I created in the query didn't go to the database. I was wondering if there's a 'right' way to do this. I tried mixing different codes that I found online, but they produce the same result.

Edit: My create table query:

```
myCommand = "CREATE TABLE tblPerson (PersonID int, LastName varchar(300), FirstName varchar(300), Address varchar(300), City varchar(300))"
```

Comment: When you run the table creation command, there are no errors ?

Comment: @KobyDouek yes there are no errors I also checked in the query editor in MSSQL. I'll add my create table query just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this is to add a USE statement before the CREATE TABLE.   So the CREATE TABLE command would look like this:

```
"USE  " & dbName & ";
GO

CREATE TABLE ..."
```

EDIT:   As pointed out in the comments, the GO separator cannot be used in a .NET SQL Command.

Instead one can use three-part naming to specify the database like this:

```
"CREATE TABLE   " & dbName & ".dbo.MyTable ( ..."
```

Or use SMO which does allow one to use the GO separator.  This technique is thoroughly described in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands).

Comment: Since the OP is doing everything via sql command the GO keyword is not going to work here. That is the default batch separator in SSMS and not a sql command. You can however use three part naming to create the new table.

Comment: @SeanLange what is 'three part naming' to create a table, where can I found information about it?

Comment: In this case it would be "Create " + dbname + ".dbo.tblPerson..." This way you can state you want to create the table in the given database and schema. As long as they are on the same server this is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks Sean, it had been a while and I forgot that you couldn't use the GO separator in a SQL command.   Three part naming will work, as you mentioned, and so should SMO, as described extensively here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands