# SQL Query Parameters

Tags: delphi

This works just fine:

```
Query  = 'SELECT * from table_1 where code = :value; ';
```

I'm however trying to use the LIKE statement and It says that It couldn't find the parameter VALUE In this case:

```
Query = 'SELECT * from table_1 where code LIKE ''%:value;%''';

Param := ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('value');
Param.DataType := ftString;
Param.Value := 'bob';
```

I wanted to use a backslash to ignore the quotes, because It works in most languages but It looks like It doesn't work in Delphi.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `;` from the value? Pretty sure that's what's throwing it off. I didn't even think that was valid SQL syntax. **EDIT** Actually, I see your problem. You can't use quotes around a parameter, but at the same time, you need the `%` in there. Instead, include `%` in the actual value you pass to the parameter, not in the statement.

Comment: That worked! thanks

Comment: Which part worked?

Comment: The second part (after the EDIT you made) I basically included the `%` with 'bob'.

Comment: @JerryDodge fyi `;` is the statement terminator in the ANSI SQL standard. However, in Microsoft's TSQL it's _usually_ optional. The place where I need it most often is when using the very powerful CTE's. To the point where I'm in the habit of prefixing them with `;` to ensure whatever previous statement may exist is terminated. E.g. `;WITH CteAlias AS (SELECT …) …`

Comment: @Craig Yeah, I'm used to using `GO` to do that using MSSQL tools.

Comment: @JerryDodge `GO` and `;` aren't equivalent. E.g. You can use `;` within a stored procedure but `GO` would be the end of the stored procedure definition (as a side-effect of ending the query batch). Also note that `GO` is actually a peculiarity of [specific client tools](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40814/224704). It's not something supported on the server. This is why query files run though SSMS don't always work when simply sent as is to the server via ADO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameters automatically put the quotes around strings for you. Therefore, you cannot include such quotes in the SQL query. Because of that, you also cannot pass the `%` syntax with the query either.

Instead, keep your statement as the original (replacing `=` with `LIKE`), and pass the `%` around the actual value instead.

```
Query = 'SELECT * from table_1 where code LIKE :value';
Param := ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('value');
Param.DataType := ftString;
Param.Value := '%bob%';
```

---

On a side note, this code's a bit more elegant...

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamValues['value']:= '%bob%';
```

No need to tell it it's a string. It will detect that automagically.

Answer (score 1):

"No need to tell it it's a string (the `Param.DataType`) . It will detect that automagically."

In general it is true.
Actually it depends of some `TConnection` properties, such as `.ParamCreate`,`.ResourceOptions.AssignedValue.rvParamCreate`, `.ResourceOptions.AssignedValue.rvDefaultParamType=false`,and `defaultParamDataType` . If those properties were not changed then 
 **It will detect that automagically**

So in some cases that would be explicit.