# Running an SQL Script using SMO In C#

Tags: c#, smo

I'm having a problem with running an SQL script in my program. This is the code for the program

```
        string databaseName = "TestDB";
        Server srv1 = new Server(@"TestServer/ABCUser");   // connects to default instance  
        srv1.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;   // set to true for Windows Authentication  
        srv1.ConnectionContext.Login = "sa";
        srv1.ConnectionContext.Password = "abcde123*";
try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(srv1.Information.Version);   // connection is established  
            if(srv1.Databases[databaseName] == null)
            {
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db;
                db = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database(srv1, databaseName);
                db.Create();
                db = srv1.Databases[databaseName];
                Console.WriteLine(db.CreateDate);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DB Already Exists!");
            }
            string sqlScript = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Projects\TrainingProject\src\TrainingDatabase\Scripts\Tables\Script01-table.sql");
            Console.WriteLine(sqlScript);
            srv1.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlScript);

        }
        catch (ConnectionFailureException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in connecting to the sql server " + e.Message);
        }
```

And this is the SQL Script

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FileTypes') BEGIN
CREATE TABLE FileTypes (
    FileTypeID tinyint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TypeName varchar(500) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT PK_FileTypes PRIMARY KEY(FileTypeID)
)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FileTypes')
    PRINT 'Created table FileTypes'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Failed to create table FileTypes'
```

END

So far, I've tested that:

1. I've managed to get the server information version(connection to server is successful)
2. I can create the database from the program
3. The script is working when I uses it as a query on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
4. The`Console.WriteLine(sqlScript);` command does show the correct SQL script

The problem is that the `srv1.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlScript);` is not working.

Anyone knows the answer?

These are the stackoverflow questions I used for reference: [Execute a large SQL script (with GO commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you seem to be recreating the functionality of DACPACs and/or `sqlcmd`. Consider just using those.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm not allowed to change it sorry

Comment: What do you get for an error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that I made a mistake in this line: `srv1.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlScript);`

It created the table in the master DB, when it should be this:

```
srv1.Databases[databaseName].ExecuteNonQuery(sqlScript);
```

Comment: If that solves your problem, then you can accept your own answer as the right answer of the question