# Dapper - Stored Procedure - Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a stored procedure in a `myscript.sql` file that looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_GetUserID]
    @EmailAddress NVARCHAR(254)
AS   
    DECLARE @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

    SELECT @UserID = [ID] 
    FROM [dbo].[User] 
    WHERE [EmailAddress] = @EmailAddress

    PRINT @UserID    
GO
```

I have some C# code that relies on Dapper to run this script. I can successfully run this script when I copy-and-paste it into Azure Data Studio. However, when I am trying to run this script from code, I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

My C# code looks like this:

```
try
{
     var script = File.ReadAllText("<path to myScript.sql is here>");

     using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
     {
         var command = connection.CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = script;
         command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

         connection.Open();
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
                
     Console.WriteLine("Success.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Failed. Reason: '{ex.Message}')");
}
```

I don't understand why I can run `myScript.sql` from Azure Data Studio, however, it's not working from my C# code. I'm also creating tables using the same approach and it works fine. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a large SQL script (with GO commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GO` is **not** a valid T-SQL keyword - it's a **separator** that is used by SQL Server Management Studio and obviously also Azure Data Studio.

To fix this, just simply remove that `GO` line from your `.sql` script file and run it without this - should be just fine.

On a different note: having nothing but a `PRINT` statement in your stored procedure doesn't make a lot of sense - don't you want to actually `SELECT @UserId` to get that data sent back to the caller??

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. You are correct that the print statement doesn't make a lot of sense. I was simply trying to reduce the problem down to something I could isolate. Regardless, removing `GO` did the trick. Thank you so much for your help.